# Disabling Cloudflare for Tor.SE?

Tags: support, feature-request, cloudflare

Our Stackexchange page sits behind a CloudFlare proxy. For Tor users this means solving CAPTCHAs. Many of them are hardly readable and quite annoying. So is there a possibility to disable the use of CloudFlare for https://*.tor.stackexchange.com/?

See below an example for a (in this case readable) CAPTCHA request:

[image: CAPTCHA when visiting Tor.SE]

Comment: I'd just like to voice my support of removing the CAPTCHA for Tor users as we our a community based on support Tor.